# Graph Coloring calculating Chromatic Polynomial

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Trying to figure out the required steps in order to calculate the Chromatic Polynomial for this graph.

I'm not too good at this topic having just started it a few days ago, but for this graph is it possible to separate the graph into 2? So the top 3 triangles as one half, and the bottom 3 as the other half?

Doing the first half I get:

$T(G,k) = k(k-1)(k-2)^3$

But I'm not sure if it would work to get the answer, would I have to use the deletion formula to get the answer, and if so which line would I have to remove?

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you have a graph $G$ made of two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ which have precisely two vertices $x,y$ **and an edge** $xy$ in common, then
$$T(G,k)=\frac1{k(k-1)}T(G_1,k)T(G_2,k).$$
This is because for every $k$-colouring of $G_1$, $x$ and $y$ must get different colours (say $x$ red and $y$ blue). The number of ways to extend this colouring to a $k$-colouring of $G$ is the number of ways to colour $G_2$ such that $x$ is red and $y$ blue. In all the $k$-colourings of $G_2$, there are $k(k-1)$ possibilities for the colours of $x$ and $y$ and each combination occurs equally often.

Therefore for each of the $T(G_1,k)$ colourings of $G_1$, there are $\frac1{k(k-1)}T(G_2,k)$ ways to extend it to a colouring of $G$.

Comment: So a simple way to do is to just separate the 2 graphs and use the formula u supplied?
Would the answer be

$\frac 1{k(k-1)}k(k-1)^2(k-2)^6$?

Comment: You're missing a factor of $k$ there, but yes: it simplifies to $k(k-1)(k-2)^6$.

Comment: Thanks, would this technique work with different graphs as well, say if I have a Triangle with a square inside, could I seperate the 2 and use this formula? Same with a square with diamond inside?

Comment: I'm not sure what graphs you're describing there, but what you need for this is basically two separate pieces glued along an edge. As long as the edge is in both of the pieces, and the pieces don't meet anywhere else, this will work.